# Detect if your server is being accessed via a jump server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I wanna see if it is possible to detect when a jump server is being used.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
Client -(ssh)-> JumpServer -(ssh)-> Server
```

Are there any logs or anything (IP addresses maybe) stored on `Server` that show that `Client` connected to it, or will it only see that the `JumpServer` connected to it and have absolutely no clue that `Client` used `JumpServer` to connect

Comment: In general, unless the proxy (the "Jump Server"), or the protocol in use, specifically announces (or leaves some kind of "origin" trace) hat a proxy is being used, here is no way to tell. The target server only "sees" the proxy machine. However, in your example, using ssh would make it clear because the certificates will not match unless there was a successful "MITM" attack.

Comment: @C.M. the certificates will not match what? JumpHosts just sets port forwarding at TCP level. You are only going to see client certificates.

Comment: @jdouitsis are you in control of either the client or the jump host?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I am in control of both the client and jump host, but I am not in control of the server

Comment: @EduardoTrápani when you say Jump Hosts sets port forwarding, does that mean the Server will not see the Jump Host since it is forwarding all of the client information? If that is the case is there some other technique to hide the client from the server via Jump Host?

Comment: Maybe I should have posted a longer, more formal answer, but the question lacks enough information. _What_ is it you want to hide? The client machine/address? The client certificate? Or something else? Is certificate pinning in use? Are you only concerned with the ssh protocol, or any protocol capable of tunneling? How is the JumpHost configured, as a simple packet forwarder, or something else? Etc.

Comment: I want to hide the client from the server so that there will be no way for the server to know that the client connected to it. Based on all of the comments and answers, I believe that that is how it works, server does not know about the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that no, there's no record of the original client stored on the final endpoint server.  The server can only detect what IP address immediately connected to it, and the connection credentials (user, password or public key).  From the server's point of view, the user is logged in from the jump host.

The only record that may exist is on the jump-host.  Though by default even that may leave no trace.  It would, by default, log the client login, but not the forwarded connection to the end server.

*Fun fact* this is why hackers are permanently trying to log in to any insecure SSH server they can find... from there that can carry out more serious attacks and make it look like the compromised machine was to blame.